# Laravel 5 cache query - get result as associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, caching

I want to cache query and get result as associative array.
When I do it without caching like this, it's okay:

```
class ItemRepositoryEloquent {

    public function getItems() {

        $items= Item::lists('word','key');

        return $items->toArray();

    }

}
```

But when I try to cache my query like this:

```
class ItemRepositoryEloquent {

    public function getItems() {

        $items = Cache::remember('items', 1440, function(){
            return Item::lists('word','key');
        });

        return $items->toArray();

    }

}
```

It returns result like this:

```
[
    0 => array('key' => 'word')
    1 => array('key' => 'word')
    2 => array('key' => 'word')
    3 => array('key' => 'word')
    4 => array('key' => 'word')
    5 => array('key' => 'word')
]
```

But I want the result to be like this after caching:

```
[
    'key' => 'word',
    'key' => 'word',
    'key' => 'word',
    'key' => 'word',
    'key' => 'word'
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide the code where you actually store them (probably your set Items function)

Comment: What do you mean by 'where I store them'?

Comment: I don't have such a function. They are stored in model Item which reffers to table items. Table items have three fields: id, key, word.

Comment: can you try to use toArray() directly within your Cache::remember function? return Item::lists('word','key')->toArray();
The problem you have is that it does not return one associative array but an array of associative arrays

Comment: I tried to, but it gives just the same result

Comment: Well - I sadly cannot think of a reason why Item::lists should return two different results here, however you could transform your result into what you need with a foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the result your looking for by using the [`collapse`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-collapse) method not sure what remember returns by default but here is an example working with a raw array

```
$collection = collect([                                                                                                                                                 
    0 => array('key1' => 'word'),                                                                                                                                           
    1 => array('key2' => 'word'),                                                                                                                                           
    2 => array('key3' => 'word'),                                                                                                                                           
    3 => array('key4' => 'word'),                                                                                                                                           
    4 => array('key5' => 'word'),                                                                                                                                           
    5 => array('key6' => 'word'),                                                                                                                                       
]);
```

then you can do

```
$collection->collapse()->toArray();
```

which will give you

```
[
     "key1" => "word",
     "key2" => "word",
     "key3" => "word",
     "key4" => "word",
     "key5" => "word",
     "key6" => "word",
]
```

Comment: I made this: `public function getItems() {
  
  $items= Cache::remember('items', 1440, function(){
   return Item::lists('word','key');
  });
  
  return $words->colllapse()->toArray();
  
 }`
It gives error 'array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array'

Comment: Did you copy and paste that you've got three `lll` in collapse. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: No, I wrote it with hand. It's okay about `lll`. I am using Laravel 5.0

Comment: Hmm seems there are some differences I tested the above in `5.2` it works also interestingly the `Cache::remember` in `5.2` with `lists` returns the `collapsed` array that you are expecting.